# Highest place possible for Jessica - heptathlon scoring

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

121 women are competing in the heptathlon in Olympic Games.

If British track and field star Jessica Ennis finishes in 104th place in every event, what is the highest place she can finish in the overall
heptathlon?

PS: Feel free to google around for the information that you think might be essential to solving the problem.

Comment: Could you describe how exactly the rating system in olympic heptathlon works?

Comment: @Philipp See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptathlon#Point_system) for point system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best she can hope for is **2nd place**.

Let's assume that in each event, there is a 103-way tie for first place. Jessica finishes 104th with a score fractionally below the leaders, and the remaining 7 competitors score precisely zero points.

Let's also assume that the winning scores in each event are equal to $X_i$ for $(1 \le i \le 7)$. So competitors who finish among the joint winners in all seven events will achieve a total score of $T = \sum^7_{i=1} X_i$, and Jessica's total score will be $(T - \epsilon)$ points, where $\epsilon$ is some small value.

If $m$ is the event where the joint winners achieved the highest score (i.e., $X_m > X_i \ \ \forall i \not= m)$, then Jessica will achieve the best position if as many as possible of the winners in event $m$ score zero in at least one other event. Since there are seventeen possible places that they can take in the remaining six events, that means Jessica can beat at most 102 of them.

So her best possible finishing position is $104 - 102 = 2$.

***(Thanks to Duncan for pointing out the glaring error in my first effort!)***

Comment: I'd look again at the details of my solution wrt the question if I were you. `:)`

Comment: squeamish - there are 121 competitors, so there are actually 17 competitors that finish behind Jessica in every event. That would put her top possible finish at 2nd (7*17 = 119).

Comment: @Duncan Good grief, I should read the questions more carefully before posting.

Comment: If there's a tie for the first place between 103 people, would you say she finished in 104th place, which the question claims she did in every event?

Comment: @Donbhupi .... yes...? Wouldn't you?

Comment: @Donbhupi Yes, you would. What would you prefer? That we say she placed second? But 103 people did better than her!

Comment: This might raise some eyebrows. "No, of *course* I didn't rig the games - those seven 103-way ties happened by chance, I swear!"

Comment: Well @squeamishossifrage as far as logic is concerned, if out of 5 people, 3 people tie for first position, the other two stand at second and third places and they would win silver and bronze medals. I'll admit your answer is correct but the way to reach there isn't. That tie isn't even needed in the first place.

Comment: @Meelo `:D` yeah people would certainly be like `o.O` but the question is all about rigging to get her to the best place, keeping in mind the conditions stated in the problem, i.e. she did finish 104th in each event.

Comment: @Donbhupi I've shown that Jessica can achieve second place in the heptathlon, so there doesn't need to be a tie for any of the medal positions in this event. You're also wrong about how medals are awarded. If two people tie for first place, the next person gets a bronze medal for third place ([this has already happened](http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/winter-olympics/26057205)).

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I see your point and I do stand corrected about the medals bit (I didn't really know about that). I'd like to clarify though that she could still finish 2nd if everyone above her didn't tie for the first place. Btw my honest feedback - you do lack thoroughness in proofreading your solution, first you read it 111 women somehow and you still have two names used for the same lady.

Comment: @Donbhupi Argh. Fixed that now. You're welcome to edit my answer if you see any other glaring errors.